# Python bot for a game

Tags: python

I just coded a very simple bot, using the "pyautogui" library.

In practice it should write a series of keys, but in my specific case I would need to use this bot in a game where it has to repeat a series of movements using the combination of these keys.

I'm not very experienced, when I launch the code by opening a notepad it writes just what I need, but if I open the game window, it doesn't press the keys (maybe because it can't type?) and starts typing directly on the pycharm terminal.

Consider that I have not used any command to activate the code on a specific program because I am a beginner and I do not know how to do it.

Do you have any solution to make this bot work on this game (it is installed directly on the pc)?
Maybe some other library for automating key clicks might work better?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide some code for us to understand and help you in the process of helping you.

Comment: Do you expect the bot to write things on the game window? Is it pygame or something?

Comment: Please share a minimal version of your code so that the community can analyze your program logic.

Comment: Is it possible your program has already finished typing what it wants to type, before you have the chance to switch over to your game? Perhaps you could put a time.sleep(10) at the top of your code to give yourself some time to switch to your game.